# Amazon iap and phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-in-app-purchase

Is it possible to use Amazon IAP with phonegap?
My issue is I developed an app with phonegap but now I want to implement amazon's iap into it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. There's Phonegap / Cordova plugin to implement Amazon IAP: https://github.com/zoxxx/cordova-plugin-amazon-in-app-purchasing . Check readme file for implementation details. Good luck!

Comment: Its been a while since I asked this but thanks and looks great.